# Custom User role not working with woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have create a custom role in wordpress using following code.

```
// register project custom post type
function custom_post_project() {
  $args = array(
    'label' => 'project',
      'public' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'project'),
      'query_var' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
      'taxonomies' => array('category'),
      'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'revisions',
        'thumbnail',
      ),
      'capability_type' => array('project', 'projects'),
      'map_meta_cap' => true,
  );
  register_post_type( 'project', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_project' );



// Add the project_manager role
add_role(
  'project_manager',
  'Project Manager',
  array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'delete_posts' => false,
    'publish_posts' => false,
    'upload_files' => true,
  )
);


// add capabilities to the role
add_action('admin_init', 'rw_add_project_role_caps', 999);
function rw_add_project_role_caps()
{

 // Add the roles you'd like to administer the custom post types
  $roles = array('project_manager');

 // Loop through each role and assign capabilities
  foreach ($roles as $the_role) {

    $role = get_role($the_role);

    $role->add_cap('read');
    $role->add_cap('read_project');
    $role->add_cap('read_private_projects');
    $role->add_cap('edit_project');
    $role->add_cap('edit_projects');
    $role->add_cap('edit_others_projects');
    $role->add_cap('edit_published_projects');
    $role->add_cap('publish_projects');
    $role->add_cap('delete_others_projects');
    $role->add_cap('delete_private_projects');
    $role->add_cap('delete_published_projects');
  }
}
```

It works perfectly fine when `woocommerce` plugin is not active. But when I active the `woocommerce` plugin. Admin user dashboard works fine. But  worpdress dashboard for the user with role `project_manager` does not work. It shows blank page with no error and no logs. I did not understand what breaks the code for only `project_manager` role user.

I have also tried `User Role Editor WordPress plugin`. Same issue with this plugin as well.
Please guide if you have any idea about that. Thanks

Comment: its working fine foe me. which theme you are using?

Comment: It is custom theme by me. It has same error with default wordpress theme

Comment: @LoicTheAztec As I mentioned I had tried `User Role Editor plugin`. Same issue with that.

Comment: post your functions.php code here